# Visual Studio 6.0 Processor pack

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 6.0 project (actually solution that includes 4 projects) that needs Processor pack to be compiled. Where I can get it? I've found links on Microsoft site, but they are leading to J# page instead of Processor pack page.

PS. Please don't advice to use the newer version of Visual Studio, I've tried all newer versions to open this project, but failed to compile it. Seems like some compiler options become wrong after converting project for beeing compatable with newer version of VS.

Comment: No, it is gone.  Part of the settlement with Sun sued them over the use of Java in VS5 and VS6.  The J# page you found noodles about it a bit at the bottom.  VS6 tends to still be available at an auction site but zero odds to find the processor pack there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Finally the problem is solved by compiling project in VS2002.